# Return in VBA, does not do what I expect

Tags: vba, excel, return

```
Public Function GetRowToWriteOn(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d7:d" & LastRow).Value
    For row = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
        If (myarray(row, 1) = id) Then
            Return row
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The IDE says expected end of statement, how do I do what I want? (Return the row where id is the same?)

I'm not familiar at all with VBA, but when I look this example from microsoft this should work? :

> The Return statement simultaneously assigns the return value and exits the function. The following example shows this.
>
> ```
> Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
>    Return 3.87 * j
> End Function
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Return a result from a VBA Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VBA, returning a value is not done through the return keyword as it is custom in other languages. 
Try:

```
GetRowToWriteOn = row
```

The function name acts as a variable on its own.

Comment: Does this return after the assignment? 
1. I don't want to loop after I'm done to save performance
2. I want to provide another value if loop doesn't find the value

Comment: `Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    Return 3.87 * j
End Function`

is same as 

`Function myFunction(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    myFunction = 3.87 * j
    Exit Function
End Function`

Comment: + 1 :) @Vixen: Replace `Return row` with `GetRowToWriteOn = row : Exit For`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Exit For will not give me the same result, see my answer:

Comment: if you like to return from a function before you reach the end, use: 

    Exit Function

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetRowToWriteOn(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal idnr As Integer) As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    myarray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("d7:d" & LastRow).Value
    For row = 1 To UBound(myarray, 1)
        If (myarray(row, 1) = idnr) Then
            GetRowToWriteOn = row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetRowToWriteOn = UBound(myarray, 1) + 1
    Exit Function 'Probably not needed :)
End Function
```

Comment: Further to my previous comment, tt depends on what you want. You can put `Exit For` as I suggested and then add this line `If GetRowToWriteOn = 0 Then GetRowToWriteOn = UBound(myarray, 1) + 1` just before `End Function` And yes, you do not need the `Exit Function` in the end as you rightly guessed :)

Comment: Yeah, I know i could exit for and then do cheking, but this way I don't make that extra conditional, also it behaves more like a return I'm used to.