# VBA Compile Error: Syntax error

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a simple function where, based on the parameter I am passing, I need to return a string value. I am getting error Compile error: Syntax error.

```
Public Function getServer(env As String) As String
    Dim serverName As String
    Select Case env
        Case "DEV"
            serverName = "abc"
            Return serverName;
         Case "TEST"
            serverName = "def"
            Return serverName;
         Case "Prod"
            serverName = "xyz"
            Return serverName;
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you're receiving? And on what line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return in VBA, does not do what I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240563/return-in-vba-does-not-do-what-i-expect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Return a result from a VBA Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Comment: @VictorK Yours is the better duplicate.

Comment: @STLDeveloper the error would be "Return without GoSub" IIRC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA doesn't use `Return` to exit a function early, or to specify the returned value of the function. In VBA, you specify early exit using `Exit Function`; and in order to return a value or object from a function, you have to assign / set the name of the function to the value / object you want to return:

```
Public Function getServer(env As String) As String
    Select Case env
        Case "DEV"
            getServer = "abc"
        Case "TEST"
            getServer = "def"
        Case "Prod"
            getServer = "xyz"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: No need for an `Exit Function` in each case. Simply`Case Else: Exit Function` and you're covered.

Comment: FYI VBA *does* have a `Return` statement. It just isn't used for that purpose (and shouldn't be used at all IMO).

Answer (score 4):

In VBA the `Return` statement (which *does* exist) serves an entirely different purpose; it's used in conjunction with the legacy `GoSub` statement, to *return* from a subprocedure jump:

```
    bar = 42
    GoSub Foo
    Exit Sub
Foo:
    Debug.Print bar
    Return
```

This type of construct is present in the language to support earlier versions/dialects of BASIC, and shouldn't be seen in modern VBA code.

Functions and `Property Get` procedures return their *return value* by assigning to the procedure's identifier:

```
getServer = "abc"
```

Note that the procedure's identifier is essentially a local variable, and thus the assignment doesn't *return*. Use `Exit Function` statements to bail out.

Also, `{NEWLINE}` is the end-of-instruction marker in VBA, not `;` semicolon ;-)

The semicolon is used in VBA to control the behavior of string-printing, e.g. `Debug.Print` and `Write#` statements.

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print 1; 2; 3;
    Debug.Print 4; 5; 6; ' prints on the same line as the previous statement
End Sub
```

Whereas this would output on 2 separate lines:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print 1; 2; 3
    Debug.Print 4; 5; 6 ' prints on the next line
End Sub
```