# VBA function returns wrong value

Tags: vba, function, excel

I am trying to assign a value to a variable by calling a function in my VBA code.

My subroutine body looks like this:

```
Sub testSubroutine()
Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = readSolOverviewTable("TOT_MAPS")
Debug.Print "Function readSolOverviewTable returned: " & iVal
End sub
```

The readSolOverviewTable  function is returning correct value with in the function itself. I have verified it by debugging the function code.

But it seems there is some problem with the subroutine code as the following statement:

```
iVal = readSolOverviewTable("TOT_MAPS")
```

Always returns 0.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
Updated:
====================================
```

my function looked like this:

```
Function readSolOverviewTable(searchVal As String) As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer
    retVal = -99

    ' Do some code and assign value to the variable retVal
    retVal = 100
    Debug.Print "retval is: " & retVal
End Function
```

As expected; this correctly shows the debug output as 100
However doesn't reflect in the subroutine call.

But changing the code to this made everything all right:

```
Function readSolOverviewTable(searchVal As String) As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer
    retVal = -99

    ' Do some code and assign value to the variable retVal
    retVal = 100
    Debug.Print "retval is: " & retVal

    readSolOverviewTable = retVal

End Function
```

Now that I have resolved the problem (I hope), what is the reason and why this weird kind of syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by `with in the function itself`? Can you post `readSolOverviewTable` content? (at least the relevant part)

Comment: Please show us code for the `readSolOverviewTable`

Comment: You may want to check [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-from-a-vba-function)

Comment: @smagnan I just checked some more posts.. And got it to work by adding one more line just before the end function statement. Updated the question with the details.

Comment: Thanks @mehow yes, I got the answer. I am new to VBA and coming from java world the VBA syntax kind of throws me off a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple - you weren't returning a value. In order to return a value from a Function in VBA, you need to say `function name = value` at the end of your code (it's like saying "return xxx"). Since you were not returning a value from the function it defaulted to 0.