# Is there a global keyword similar to C's "Return" for returning values from a VBA function?

Tags: vba, excel

Not being entirely sure how to best articulate the title, I'll try to explain myself better here..

I do a lot of cutting and pasting of templated chunks of code that I repeat in most of my functions - typically, error handling and debugging facilities in general.

As returning values from functions is done by declaring `MyFunction = "SomeValue"`, I figure there is little harm in asking if there is any way of generalizing away "MyFunction" (in this example)?

E.g.:

```
Function MyFunction() As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    ' <..do stuff here..>
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    MyFunction = "Something bad happened"

End Function
```

So if I were to copy this chunk as a template for all my future functions, I would love not having to replace every occurrence of the word `MyFunction` in the code.. So I wonder if there is some arbitrary keyword like `Me` to return the function's resultant value like you would use the *Return* function in C.

Hope that made sense!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Return from a VBA Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-from-a-vba-function)

Comment: basically, the answer is, "No"

Comment: Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264233%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's the way the language is specified. If you want to return a value from the `X` function, you "assign" the value to `X`:

```
Function MyFunction() As String
    MyFunction = "Hello"
End Function
```

And keep in mind, that doesn't actually *finish* execution of your function, if you want that, you need to explicitly exit the function as well:

```
Function MyFunction() As String
    If a = 1 Then
        MyFunction = "Hello"
        Exit Function
    End If
    MyFunction = "Bye"
End Function
```

Without the `exit function` line in the above code, the function will return `Bye` rather than `Hello`.

If you *really* want a new keyword to do the work of both those statements, you could petition Microsoft for a change, but I don't think much of your chances since there's already a perfectly good way of doing it :-) They're likely to just come back and tell you to use C++ or C# if you want those constructs.