# Compile error Expected: end of statment

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, return

I've got some code that works perfectly fine, but I wanted to add something to it. So I made one of my functions return a value. But, no matter what I return, I get the "Compile error Expected: end of statment" msgbox appearing.

I eventually did this to my code, and I still get the error.
Can someone please explain this?

```
Public Function Addresses() As Integer
 return 1

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [this post](http://Duplicate%20of%20[this%20post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)), but basically you need to assign the function name the value, for example:

```
Addresses = 1
```

instead of

```
return 1
```

Comment: I actually found quite a few posts on google trying to find it, but not that one. I promise I tried. lol That's dumb. I don't like VBA. But, Thank you. It worked.