# VBA write function and return value

Tags: vba, excel, function, subroutine

I am trying to call a sub routine in another sub routine and want to return some values. However it doesn't seem to return any value. How would I write this as a function ? The code is the following:

```
Sub tickersymbolchange()

 Dim RSTA_ISIN, RSTA_Currency, RSTA_Ticker As String

For Each rng In r

         ticker_wo_equity = Replace(rng.Value, " Equity", "")
         Exchangecode = Right(ticker_wo_equity, 2)

         Select Case Exchangecode
            Case "PO", "L3", "B3", "S2", "TQ", "SS"

                'MsgBox "I am in PO"

                Call getRSTA_POL3B3S2TQSSIXEB(ticker_wo_equity, RSTA_ISIN, RSTA_Currency, RSTA_Ticker)

                'Get ISIN from Rsta
                If IsEmpty(RSTA_ISIN) Then
                     rng.Offset(0, 11) = "N/A"
                Else
                     rng.Offset(0, 11) = RSTA_ISIN
                End If


                'Get Currency from Rsta
                If IsEmpty(RSTA_Currency) Then
                    rng.Offset(0, 12) = "N/A"
                Else
                    rng.Offset(0, 12) = RSTA_Currency
                End If
End select

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub getRSTA_POL3B3S2TQSSIXEB(ticker, Optional ByVal getISIN As String, Optional ByVal getCurrency As String, Optional ByVal getTicker As String, Optional ByVal getUS As String, Optional ByVal getTickerTicker_IBEX As String, Optional ByVal getPriceCode_GR As String)

    BBs.Send ticker & "<Equity> RSTA"
    BBs.Go
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    'Sleep 1000

    BBs.CopyScreen

    getISIN = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 13)
    getCurrency = BBs.GetTextField(7, 15, 4)
    getTicker = BBs.GetTextField(7, 20, 6)
    getUS = BBs.GetTextField(7, 11, 9)
    getTickerTicker_IBEX = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 7)
    getPriceCode_GR = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 7)

End Sub
```

So here I am trying to give RSTA_ISIN to the function getRSTA_POL... and then the function should assign RSTA_ISIN the value of getISIN, however RSTA_ISIN and all the other parameters are always empty.

Comment: If you want to change the values of the parameters passed into the sub, use `byRef`, not `byVal`. After you've changed the values and fallen out of the sub the original vars passed in will hold the new values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Return a result from a VBA Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code use a `Call` for your subroutine, you can use this but it actually avoid having any output from the function!

Secondly, you need to use `ByRef` instead of `ByVal` if you want to affect the value of your arguments inside of the procedure or function. `ByVal` will create a copy of the inputed argument and though won't affect the initial variable!

Finally, you need to transform the second Sub into a Function and define the type of output (here I set it as a String) and then assign the function output to a variable, like this :

```
Public Function test_Function() As Integer
    test = 1
End Function
Sub Test()
    Dim Result as Integer
    Result = test_Function
    MsgBox Result 
End Sub
```

Here is your revised code :

```
Sub tickersymbolchange()
Dim RSTA_ISIN As String, RSTA_Currency As String, RSTA_Ticker As String
For Each Rng In r
    ticker_wo_equity = Replace(Rng.Value, " Equity", "")
    Exchangecode = Right(ticker_wo_equity, 2)

    Select Case Exchangecode
       Case "PO", "L3", "B3", "S2", "TQ", "SS"
           RSTA_ISIN = getRSTA_POL3B3S2TQSSIXEB(ticker_wo_equity, RSTA_ISIN, RSTA_Currency, RSTA_Ticker)
           'Get ISIN from Rsta
           If IsEmpty(RSTA_ISIN) Then
                Rng.Offset(0, 11) = "N/A"
           Else
                Rng.Offset(0, 11) = RSTA_ISIN
           End If
           'Get Currency from Rsta
           If IsEmpty(RSTA_Currency) Then
               Rng.Offset(0, 12) = "N/A"
           Else
               Rng.Offset(0, 12) = RSTA_Currency
           End If
    End Select
Next Rng
End Sub

Function getRSTA_POL3B3S2TQSSIXEB(ticker, Optional ByRef getISIN As String, _
                            Optional ByRef getCurrency As String, _
                            Optional ByRef getTicker As String, _
                            Optional ByRef getUS As String, _
                            Optional ByRef getTickerTicker_IBEX As String, _
                            Optional ByRef getPriceCode_GR As String) As String
    BBs.Send ticker & "<Equity> RSTA"
    BBs.Go
    'Sleep 1000
    BBs.CopyScreen

    getISIN = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 13)
    getCurrency = BBs.GetTextField(7, 15, 4)
    getTicker = BBs.GetTextField(7, 20, 6)
    getUS = BBs.GetTextField(7, 11, 9)
    getTickerTicker_IBEX = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 7)
    getPriceCode_GR = BBs.GetTextField(7, 2, 7)

getRSTA_POL3B3S2TQSSIXEB = getISIN
End Function
```

Comment: If I use this it gives me the error ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: It is because you didn't declare `RSTA_ISIN, RSTA_Currency` as String. See and test the edit! ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all **Functions are declared differently**:

```
Function GetLong()
   GetLong = 10
End Function

Sub GetLong()
  GetLong = 10 'WRONG!!!
End Sub
```

Secondly, you can only define a variable provided to a procedure if you send it by it's reference (pointer) not by value:

```
Sub SetLong(ByRef myLong as Long)
   myLong = 10
End Sub
```

So it all comes to replacing :
`ByVal getISIN As String`
with
`ByRef getISIN As String`

[Here you can find a tutorial on Procedures vs. Functions](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/#Procedures_vs_Functions).

Comment: If I use this it gives me the error ByRef argument type mismatch