# Freight price in particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to bring our freight price in workbook 1, Cell B14.

The freight price varies based on freight weight:

- If the freight weight is less than 45 kg, freight price is 55.00 HKD
- If the weight is greater than 45 kg, freight price is 47.00 HKD
- If the weight is greater than 100 kg, freight price is 29,50 HKD

The VBA I have so far is listed below, but I get [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJu4x.jpg): `statement invalid outside Type block`. How to make this work?

```
Public Function freightrate()

    Weight As Double
    freightrate As Double

    Weight = Cells(B, 8).Value
    freightrate = Cells(B, 14).Value

    If Weight < 45 Then
        freightrate = 55
    ElseIf Weight > 45 < 100 Then
        freightrate = 47
    ElseIf Weight > 100 < 300 Then
        freightrate = 29,50
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Uday, sorry but we're not goint to solve the problem from scratch for you. Try to solve it and we will help make it work and make it efficient.

Comment: > I get error message for bellow stated programPublic Function freightrate()
Weight As Double
freightrate As Double
Weight = Cells(B, 8).Value
freightrate = Cells(B, 14).Value
If Weight < 45 Then
freightrate = 55
ElseIf Weight > 45 < 100 Then
freightrate = 47
ElseIf Weight > 100 < 300 Then
freightrate = 29,50
End If

Comment: copy the code to your original question, format it correct and post also the error message; instead of "ElseIf Weight > 45 < 100" Then try "ElseIf Weight > 45 And Weight < 100 Then"

Comment: same of course for the other comparisons where you have more then one value. BTW: it's better to use Select-Case instead of that If/ElseIf combinantions

Answer (score 0):

Wah, my VBA time is wayyy back. I think you have 2 problems here, variable definition and scope.

1- To define variables you missed a `Dim`:

```
Dim Weight As Double
```

2- In VBA ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)) you use the name of the function as a return value. I think what is causing your trouble here is the

```
freightrate As Double
```

Remove it or use a temp variable and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As cboden said - better to use SELECT CASE.
This can also be used as a worksheet function - **=freightrate(Sheet1!B14)** for example.
The function returns a VARIANT so that the ELSE statement can return the error - you may want to change it to CVErr(xlErrNum) to show a #Num! error instead - or change the return type to a Double if you want to do away with the error capture.
You could also use **CASE > 300**

```
Public Sub Test()

    Debug.Print freightrate(Range("B14").Value)

End Sub

Public Function freightrate(Weight As Double) As Variant

    Select Case Weight
        Case 45
            freightrate = 55
        Case 46 To 100
            freightrate = 47
        Case 100 To 300
            freightrate = 29.5
        Case Else
            freightrate = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End Select


End Function
```