# Using a function to clean data in VBA

Tags: vba

I am familiar with this post: [How to Return a result from a VBA Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function) but changing my code does not seem to help.

I want to write a simple function in VBA that allows to lowercase an input sentence. I wrote this:

```
Private Function Converter(inputText As String) As String
 Converter = LCase(inputText) 
End Function

Sub test()
 Dim new_output As String
 new_output = Converter("Henk")
 MsgBox (new_output)
End Sub
```

I tried following the advice I found at another stackoverflow post. I made me change this:

```
Private Function Converter(inputText As String)
 Set outputText = LCase(inputText)
End Function

Sub test()
 Dim new_output As String
 Set new_output = Converter("Henk")
 MsgBox (new_output)
End Sub
```

However, now I get an error that an object is required. Why does it require an object now? I dont get it...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Set outputText = LCase(inputText)
> ```

The `Set` keyword is reserved for *Object* data types. Unlike VB.NET, `String` in VBA is a *basic* data types.

So you dont `Set` a variable to a string. Drop the second version of your code altogether. It doesn't make sense. That "advice" was probably in another context.

To fix your first version

1- Assign the returned result to the name of the function `Converter`
2- It would be beneficial to specify explicitly the return type, as `String`. Currently it is a `Variant` that always embeds a `String`, so better make it explicit:

```
'                                               vvvvvvvvv
Private Function Converter(inputText As String) As String
  Converter = LCase(inputText) ' <------------ assign return to name of function
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for you advice. Could explain what changes I should make to get this working?

Comment: @HenkStraten also, although it occasionally works, better use `MsgBox new_output` without parentehsis, that's the correct syntax.

Comment: sorry for bothering. But I just edited my code according to your advice. But still a missing object error. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no error now in your first version. As for the second version that comes after *"I tried following the advice I found at another stackoverflow post"* throw it to the thrash bin.