# Passing the position of a button to a calling sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure how to ask this question and I'm relatively new to the community.

I am trying to get the position of a button, which I have the code for, and it works.

How can I call the Sub below from another Sub and get the integer value of the row position?

```
Sub ButtonRow()
     ' Mainlineup Macro
    Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        RowNumber = .Row
    End With
    'MsgBox "Row Number " & RowNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Return a result from a VBA Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass variables around in VBA.

You can either use Public variables outside of the function, which will have scope outside of their sub, or use a [Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/writing-a-function-procedure), which is designed to return output.

Note that global public variables have certain security implications.

Functions must be named as the variable you intend to return - in this case `Function RowNumber()`. There are limitations on what you can do with Functions - IIRC functions cannot change any cell, worksheet, or workbook properties.

```
Sub WhatPosition()
    MsgBox RowNumber
End Sub

Public Function RowNumber() As Integer
    Dim b As Object
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller) 
    With b.TopLeftCell 
        RowNumber = .Row 
    End With 
End Function
```

or:

```
Public RowNumber As Integer

Sub WhatPosition()
    ButtonRow
    MsgBox RowNumber
End Sub

Sub ButtonRow() 
    Dim b As Object 
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller) 
    With b.TopLeftCell 
        RowNumber = .Row 
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You so much! i tried the code, but ran into a problem. When i called the function, and tested to see if the position row was passed; the variable was empty. What if I made the variable Global to be accessed by other subs. Would that work too?

Comment: Not sure if you can use `ActiveSheet` within a function. They have a lot of structural limitation. You might have to use the second example I posted. Or pass it the name of the current worksheet.