# Support with the Return Function

Tags: vba, return, return-value

I am having a bit of trouble with the return function on VBA and was hoping someone would be able to help me troubleshoot the issue.

Here is the function:

```
Function Hypotenuse(side1 As Double, side2 As Double) As Double
Return Math.Sqrt((side1 ^ 2) + (side2 ^ 2))
End Function
```

Summary of the Issue:

- The return function is highlighted in 'red' and I am unable to run any sub-routine that calls the function (see attached picture)
- Pretty sure the code is code is correct, but i simply do not understand why I keep getting an error

Any idea why this may be happening?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: You need to assign `Hypotenuse` to a `Double` Variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a result from a VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Answer (score 1):

Use Sqr function .. and no Return keyword in VBA

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Hypotenuse(5, 3)
End Sub

Function Hypotenuse(side1 As Double, side2 As Double) As Double
    Hypotenuse = Sqr((side1 ^ 2) + (side2 ^ 2))
End Function
```