# Error Object Variable Not Set when not using Set

Tags: excel, vba, object

I keep running into the error message "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set", however, when I use SET to set the variable then I get the same error despite having set it. Does anyone know why this may be happening? This is my code I have and the line that keep throwing the two errors is

name = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)

The error gets thrown so early that the code cannot even try running getdata so I have not yet been able to debug that to see if it works entirely. Before calling getdata, the function getcolumnindex runs fine. Here is my entire code

```
Public Sub Main() 

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object, wbSrc As Workbook 

Dim value As Long 

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 

For Each i In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells 
 sysnum = i.value 
 sysrow = i.Row 
 syscol = i.Column 

getcolumnindex ws, "Range (nm)" 
value = getdata(sysrow, "Range (nm)") 

Next i 

End Sub
```

---

```
Function getcolumnindex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Integer 

Dim name As Range, colind As Integer 
## Error gets thrown at this line below 
Set name = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname,Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) 
   If Not name Is Nothing Then 
        colind = name.Column 
        MsgBox name & " column index is " & colind 
   End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function getdata(WDrow As Integer, parametercol As String) 

Dim cell As Variant, ws As Worksheet 

cell = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range (nm)") 
Data = Cells(WDrow, parametercol) 
MsgBox (Data) 

End Function
```

Comment: @BigBen It does find the `colname` as it works when it is on its own. Its when combined with `getdata` does it throw the error. I know that it does because the messagebox appears printing the column index

Comment: @BigBen So I can write `Set name = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)

Comment: @BigBen Unfortunately, even with adding the two lines it did not get rid of the error

Comment: @BigBen I just did

Comment: @BigBen Ok, that did not remove the error

Comment: @resu you are setting a value to `Data` instead of `getdata` For the Function to return anything. That has been the issue all along. change `Data = Cells(WDrow, parametercol) ` to `getdata = Cells(WDrow, parametercol)`

Comment: @BigBen adding the message box has it return False then the column index message box and then true.

Comment: @BigBen I would like for the result of getcolumnindex to be used in the getdata function as one of the inputs.

Comment: @RicardoA Sadly, the error "Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set" still occurs

Comment: Because both functions are doing the same thing, Basic function behavior: for a function to return something assign a value to the function name. example: Function GiveMeData() GiveMeData = `Returned Data' End Function, you are not using the Function name, therefor nothing is being returned.

Comment: @RicardoA So I have to write another function to assign value? I cant just write `parametername = getcolumnindex(ws, "Range (nm)")

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues. Among them, in `getdata`,

- `ws` is not `Set`.
- `Cells(WDrow, parametercol)` implicitly refers to the `ActiveSheet`, but really needs to have its parent worksheet specified.
- `MsgBox (Data)` should not have any parentheses.
- `Data` is an undeclared variable.

```
Function getdata(WDrow As Integer, parametercol As String) 

   Dim cell As Variant, ws As Worksheet 

   cell = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range (nm)")  'ws is never Set
   Data = Cells(WDrow, parametercol)
   MsgBox Data 

End Function
```

It would be good to read up on the difference between `Sub`s and `Function`s, and how to return a value from a `Function`.

`getcolumnindex` returns `0`, *always*. If you want `getcolumnindex` to return something, you need the line

```
getcolumnindex = ...
```

within the function.

The following line does nothing with the return value of `getcolumnIndex`.

```
getcolumnindex ws, "Range (nm)"
```

This does nothing with the return value of `getcolumnIndex`.

Comment: I would highly suggest reading up on the difference between `Sub`s and `Function`s, and how to return a value from a `Function`. None of your functions are returning what you think they are.

Comment: So I should format it to be similar to `value = getdata(sysrow, "Range (nm)")`

Comment: First read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function).

Comment: Using the readings I have made this change `Function getcolumnindex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Integer
    Dim paramname As Range
    Set paramname = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not paramname Is Nothing Then
            getcolumnindex = paramname.Column
            MsgBox paramname & " column index is " & getcolumnindex
        End If
End Function`