# VBA Boolean function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function Check() As Boolean

    Check = True

End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    dim a as Boolean = Check()
    
End Sub
```

I was trying to make a bool function that checked each textbox and gave me back a true/false value with msgbox, but when i tried to call the function it gave me a compilation error: expected various, i tried to put it public but nothing changed.

Comment: You can't create a variable like that - `Dim` on one row, assign value to the variable on another.

Comment: Check Here [How to return a result from a VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you can't declare ***and*** assign in the same command like that, you would do this instead:

```
Function Check() As Boolean

    Check = True

End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim a As Boolean
    a = Check()
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is because the Check() function is not declared as a Public function. In order to call a function from another procedure, it must be declared as Public.

To fix this, you need to change the declaration of the Check() function to the following:

Public Function Check() As Boolean

```
Check = True
```

End Function
Once you have made this change, the function should be able to be called from the CommandButton1_Click() procedure.

Here is the complete code:

Function Check() As Boolean

```
Check = True
```

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim a As Boolean
a = Check()
```

End Sub
This code will create a Check() function that returns a Boolean value of True. The CommandButton1_Click() procedure will then call the Check() function and store the result in the a variable.

To test the code, you can run the macro by pressing F5. The Check() function will return a value of True, and the a variable will be assigned the value of True.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT