# Checking if a number is prime does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Visual Basic for Applications code:

```
Function IsPrimeTrialDivision(number As Long) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    If number <= 1 Then
        IsPrime = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 2 To Sqr(number)
        If number Mod i = 0 Then
            IsPrime = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    IsPrime = True
End Function
```

And I am using it in an Excel document. The logic seems fine, but it is always returning `FALSE`:

[image: Showing it always returns false]

Why is it not working?

Comment: It does not compile! You must assign the values to `IsPrimeTrialDivision` instead of `IsPrime`. It says "variable not defined" for `IsPrime`.

Comment: Or rename the function to `IsPrime` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function isn't returning a value.  [Here's a post detailing that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781689/how-to-return-a-result-from-a-vba-function)

Adding the line `IsPrimeTrialDivision = IsPrime` at the end of the function will assign the value to the function's return.

Answer (score 3):

You get `False` result of the function because there is no assigning of the function name. Therefore the return value is 0, which means as a `Boolean` a `False` value.
To return a value from a function there must be an assignment to the exact function name before returning from it.

Answer (score -1):

It seams you are calling Test() function only.
Use the following in inside your Test function
`//Test = False`
`Test = isPrimeTrialDevision(number)`
hope this will solve your issue.